# Is this statement gramatically correct ? - " All we seek is the tiniest of drop in an ocean of knowledge"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I see two versions to it being correct.

1)- *All we seek is the tiniest drop in an ocean of knowledge.*

2)- *All we seek are the tiniest of drops in an ocean of knowledge.*

I want to know if the original sentence is correct as well ?

Comment: better:  "All we seek are the tiniest drops of knowledge in an ocean of such."

Comment: The phrsase sounds a bit strange to my ears and I'm wondering about the metaphor.  A bit more context would be useful. For instance, is the ocean of knowledge the knowledge that humankind possesses or is it more potential knowledge? If the second -- if for instance you are speaking of discovering the secrets of the universe of which so little is known, you may need another metaphor.

Comment: @SConroy It is the knowledge which mankind possesses. Is the original sentence in the question grammatically correct ? More specifically "is the tiniest of drop in an ocean" correct or should it be "is the tiniest of drops" ?

Comment: ***All that glitters is not gold*** is a well-known proverb![https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=pX6BW6bVFMiw9QPgk6Bw&q=all+that+glitters+is+not+gold&oq=All+that+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.3366.5684.0.7894.9.9.0.0.0.0.247.1076.0j5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.6.1072...0i131k1j0i10k1.0.5b9uJX-k2yk]

Comment: @user313741, Grammatically both of your sample sentences are correct, but your title sentence isn't; it has to be 'the tiniest drop' or 'the tiniest of drops' as you yourself suggested, but not as per title 'the tiniest of drop'.

Comment: PS You can't say 'the tiniest of drop' because you can't have the tiniest of only one thing.

Answer (score 0):

All we seek is the tiniest drop in a ocean of knowledge.
tiniest dog, tiniest cat, tiniest grain - no "of" in between.

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange. We as a community strongly encourage users to provide as detailed an explanation as possible in their answer, for the benefit of the enquirer and community as a whole. As it stands, however, your response to this question seems to lack any form of citation. Therefore, we would like for you to edit this answer, and to provide sufficient evidence to back it up. Please refer to the Help Center if you have any further questions.

Comment: I saw the tiniest of dogs yesterday.